# php array date DDMMYY

Tags: php, date

I have a form and when it submits to my email it shows YYMMDD.
I need it to show DDMMYY.
The code in the backend looks like this:

```
// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from booking form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('pickupdate' => 'Pick Up Date' , 'message' => 'Message');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
```

How do i get the DDMMYY for the array field `pickupdate`.

Comment: can you share exact date ? and expected output ?

Comment: It is for an online form. so the user selects the date and it shows on the front of the site   dd/mm/yyyy  on the email when the form is submitted I get  YYYY-MM-DD.  
I need the date first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_create_from_format()`:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Y-M-j', '2009-Feb-15');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the date into a real date and then reformat it, but I would prefer to just get out the bits you need in the order, in which you need them. Like this:

```
$oldDate = '180728';
$newDate = substr($oldDate,4,2).substr($oldDate,2,2).substr($oldDate,0,2);
echo $newDate;
```

This will return:

```
280718
```

this way there's no change of the date functions changing the date in any way due to any time settings, which sometimes can happen (when you least expect it).

Answer (score 0):

If you split the string in parts of 2, then reverse the array and implode back to string it's reversed order of date.

```
$str = "121314";

echo implode("",array_reverse(str_split($str, 2)));
//141312
```

https://3v4l.org/cZWJk

Answer (score -1):

Simply pass your date variable inside strtotime().

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime("$date"));
```

Comment: It works,but input must contain slash.  3v4l.org/1d9e0

Comment: But the string does not contain slashes this your code does not work

Comment: Yes, but we can use input type=date rather than text, so that it automatically inserts slashes for you.and it supports in all moden browsers.

Comment: But that is not the question. Answer the question stated at the top of the page. If you want to answer a question with slashes then find a question with slashes and answer that question. This question is different.

Comment: Okay..understood.but if you look at the question by @Melzy, it does contain slashes.